# toggle numlock with assembly

Tags: windows, x86, assembly

I need a simple program that toggles numlock key, to be written in assembly. I googled this problem and I found these pages:

[Art of Assembly 1](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH20/CH20-4.html)

[Art of Assembly 2](http://oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_20/CH20-3.html)

but because of my little experience in assembly, they lead me to no where.
any idea and help appreciated.

Comment: Which OS? And why assembly? Why not a higher-level language?

Comment: windows-x86. sorry I totally forgot to mention it

Comment: Does your program need to use the Windows routines, or is it supposed to use BIOS or direct hardware calls?

Comment: BIOS or system call or any other way, there is no difference, I just need to get it done in a low-level code

Comment: @mk.persia Is this for shellcode?

Comment: Link rot, no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the Windows API, then look into the **keybd_event** function. I'm pretty sure you can call it from assembly. Just google how to do it. I have successfully used this function in VB.Net to toggle CAPS Lock. I have not programmed in Intel assembly language in about 8-9 years.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: "Note: This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I didn't even see that it had been superseded. My eyes went straight down to the syntax section. I checked, and the program still works, though. If I ever have need of using it again, I will change the function call.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure what's quite so bad about keybd_event. I just look at MSDN and to what it tells me to...

Answer (score 0):

Call [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx). It's possible to call this from assembly, although much easier through a higher-level language. For instance, you could write the SendInput call in C, then call your C routine from assembly.